# Access DevOps build/release information from .NET code

Tags: asp.net, azure-devops

Is there a way to access DevOps build or release information during runtime of the project that was built? I would like to provide a link to the DevOps page containing logs of the actual release from an ASP.NET web page (of course for admins only).